# Problems finding and highlighting elements via iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors, highlight

I'm trying to create somewhat of a highlighting/selecting tool [using jQuery] in my web app that watches what elements you hover over inside an iFrame, selects the hovered-over element, and uses that element's styling to create on overlaying `<div>`. Think of the element selection tool in your web inspector.

Here's a demo uses `p`,`a`, and `h2` elements as the selector (hover over one): http://jsfiddle.net/ST539/1/

The problem I'm having is that this only seems to work on some web pages, and I'm not sure what is causing this. Here's another demo using *example.com*: http://jsfiddle.net/ST539/2/

No highlight on any elements. Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). JavaScript can't access `iframe`d `document`s from different domains.

There are some workarounds but most clean ones require some setting up in the other domain's page. See: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Sorry for being the bringer of these news, but yes, same origin police is a very important security aspect. For example, imagine that you are `iframe`'ing ads in your page, you wouldn't like those to modify your parent page. `=]` Most of the workarounds listed above require some form of "authenticating" the access so the other page must allow access to it.

Comment: Though, you may want to look into making a browser extension or something, Chrome extensions are not hard to make and don't have such restrictions I believe.

Comment: Perhaaaaaps you might be able to help with this question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228317/using-jquery-to-highlight-elements-cant-get-to-inner-elements